# How to create Trailing functions for selected controls?

Tags: javascript, function, object

Lately i have taken the tutorials D3 from here [D3 - Data Driven Documents tutorials](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/d3js/animated-bar-chart-d3)

anyway, i have a project i need to build some charts for and i was planning to create a library to generate charts based on project requirements with professional approach of code.

like **jquery** library has:

```
$('#someSelector').someFunction();
```

so far i know how to objectify the functionalities like:

```
someModuleFunctionality = {
        getStuff = function(objParams){//bring data},
        sendStuff = function(objParams){//save data},
        someCalculations  = function(i,j,k){//some calculations}
   }
```

but it doesn't let me use these things as i want them to use like:

```
myProjectLibrary('#someSelector').buildBarChart();
```

I am not willing my library to be dependent on Jquery, just like D3. I will appreciate the help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return an object from your `myProjectLibraryMethod` function.

```
function myProjectLibraryMethod(arg) {
    doStuff.with(arg);
    return new MyProject(arg);
}
```

Then you just attach the methods to `MyProject`.

```
function MyProject() {
    this.buildBarChart = function() { /* Build bar chart */ };
    //Other methods...
}
```

Comment: appreciate all the answers as they all have given me understanding of the concept with different approaches, but yours is clean and organized, thank you everyone.

Comment: would you please join me on [SQL channel](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11391/sql)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a function named `myProjectLibrary` which returns an object which has a function `buildBarChart()`

```
function myProjectLibrary(selector) {
  let element = document.querySelector(selector);

  if (element) {
      element.buildBarChart = () => {
          // code to build bar chart
      }
  }

  return element;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this based on your requirements if you want to be able to access the methods only. Then you can just return the functions as objects or someModuleFunctionality that you have. for e.g:

```
function myLibrary() {
  let someModuleFunctionality = {
    /** Your functions here */
  }
  return someModuleFunctionality;
}
```

But if you want to be able to chain functions like in jquery you need to return the reference of the mainLIbrary function in each methods for e.g:

```
function myProjectLibrary(selector) {
  getStuff = () => {
    this.data = selector.data;
    return this;
  }

  logStuff = msg => {
    console.log(`${msg} ${data}`);
    return this;
  }
  return {
    getStuff, 
    logStuff
  }
}

myProjectLibrary({data: 'World'}).getStuff().logStuff("Hello");
```

You can then continue chaining functions as much as you like.